# Simple login with PHP check against Microsoft Access

Tags: php, database, ms-access, authentication

i'm new to PHP. I created a microsoft access database with user A and pw 123 (testing). I tried to find on the website but unfortunately I can't find any that can actually lead me to authenticate against MS Access, most of the website is purely about SQL, which is what i really do not want, please help!

Currently here are my codes

Login.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
// dBase file
include "database.php";

<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>  
<fieldset >  
<legend>Please log in your employee ID and Password to apply for leave.</legend>  
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
<br>  
<label for='username'>UserName*:</label>  
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />  
<br>
<label for='password'>Password*:&nbsp;</label>  
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />  
<br><br>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />  
</fieldset>
```

Database.php

```
 <?php
 // This part sets up the connection to the 
 // database (so you don't need to reopen the connection
 // again on the same page).
 $conn=odbc_connect("employee","","") or die (odbc_errormsg());
 if (!$conn )
 {
 exit
 ("Error connecting to database: ".$conn);
 }
 // Then you need to make sure the database you want
 // is selected.
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM empTable";
 $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
 ?>
```

How do i continue from here? Thank you! Please note that I can only authenticate everything with MS Access 2003.

Comment: Please, please don't use MS Access for your database. :(

Comment: Hi Amber, I've no choice. Superior asked me to use it :( Anyway I got the help of simple login by tweaking the answers here and there through this website ! http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/794640-simple-login-using-ms-access-odbc

Comment: Does your query execute or you get errors? do you have a Users table with user names & passwords? where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Yaniro, I'm not stucked anymore, I got the help from the previous comment. I'm really sorry, and yes i was stucked at thinking of how to do a login function with a user table with username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    session_start(); 

    // Get the data collected from the user 
    $Username =$_POST["username"]; 
    $Password =$_POST["password"]; 

    if (!$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection")) 
    exit("Unable to create an ADODB connection
"); 
    $strConn = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" . realpath("DATABASEFILE"); 
    $conn->open($strConn); 

    $strSQL = "SELECT username, password FROM accounts WHERE username = '$Username' AND   password = '$Password'"; 
    $rs = $conn->execute($strSQL); 

    if (!$rs->EOF) 
    { 
      if ( $rs->Fields["Username"]->value 
           && $rs->Fields["Username"]->value == $Username 
           && $rs->Fields["Password"]->value 
           && $rs->Fields["Password"]->value == $Password 
         ) 
      { 
         $_SESSION["authenticatedUser"] = $Username; 
         // Relocate to the logged-in page 
         header("Location: loggedon.php"); 
      } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Login Error as $Username. " ; 
      header("Location: admin.php"); 
    }
```